# Action or script for saving files in Photoshop using text from clipboard as the file name

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, photoshop-scripting, save, actions

I make images for an online retail site and I've made several actions to make it go faster.  I have an action that automatically saves multiple files for web using generic filenames such as "tee_XXX_Detail240x600". This action works great, but I  must manually re-name these by replacing the "XXX" with the title of the design. It takes some time to do this, of course.
  Is there a way to make an action or script that uses text from the clipboard to name the file?  I tried recording the action while pasting the filename from the clipboard into the save box, but it didn't record it as I thought it might.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the export script to do what you want, but from your use-case I would judge that **mass-renaming** is better suited for you.
Because renaming, even complex exchange of words, can be automated, for example with app like [NameChanger](http://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/).

Examples from the website:

> Replace First Occurrence
>
> Replace Last Occurrence
>
> Replace All Occurrences
>
> Wildcard
>
> Append
>
> Prepend
>
> Date
>
> Sequence
>
> Character Removal
>
> Regular Expression